# Find out which exceptions a certaing class throws

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

When I click Ctrl+Q in IntelliJ, I do not get info on which exceptions a certain class throws. I can see this if I click Shift+F1 (view external docs) and then browse the entire class.

Is there any faster way to get this info in IntelliJ?

Comment: Classes don't throw exceptions, methods do.

Comment: LOL. of course, but you know what I meant :))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pulled from the javadoc (the @throws annotation) so if it's in the javadoc for a method and you highlight a method and press control-q if it throws any exceptions, it should show you.

Comment: That's it. I was checking the object instead of its methods. Thanks! Ctrl+Q works flawlessly!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no easier way since the exceptions are not thrown by the class, but by its methods.

Comment: ColinD told me the same. I know that but at the moment of creating a post, I wrote classes instead of class' methods. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try invoking Ctrl-Shift-F7 on the "throws" keyword in a method declaration.
It shows the location(s) in the method body where that exception is thrown.

Not exactly what you asked for (I think), but might come in handy.